# send a gmail for the people who search my key words

Tags: asp.net, gmail

I have a project that I want to choose some key words, and when people search these words in google, an automatic gmail send to them.
I want to know if google have API for this? I cannot found it
thanks a lot

Comment: You will **never** be able to do that.

Comment: Are you sure? I see a software that do this. It's name is marketo

Comment: Not from Google searches.

Comment: @slaks Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes.  **You can't do that.**

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this for you.

1. Google will never provide real time personally identifiable information to anybody as would be a violation of their own privacy policy.
2. If a user is not signed in, Google would have to hack the users computer to obtain the email which would be illegal.
3. If Google ever did this nobody would ever use them because this feature would be abused like you wouldn't believe.

So the only way this would be possible would to install spyware onto said users computer, which is likely illegal and morally questionable.

Comment: Lol on the edit mason